# what could cause pragma once in c / cpp file

Tags: c++, c

I'm wondering what could go wrong when I will have bigger C / C++ project with multiple modules and I will by mistake type `#pragma once` into some c / cpp file. Will it just spit warnings at me and ignore the pragma or can it somehow break my project?

**EDIT:**

This is just teoretical question. There are no more details.

Answer (score 3):

`#pragma once` serves as a header guard similar to:

```
#ifndef MY_INCLUDED_FILE
#define MY_INCLUDED_FILE
....
#endif
```

This just makes sure that a certain file is compiled only once even if it is included multiple times.

If a compiler doesn't support a certain `pragma` it will simply ignore it.
On older compilers it may not be known, so you have to use the `ifdef` solution. If the compiler doesn't understand it, and you don't have the header guard, then you probably will get a lot of errors for duplicate definitions and similar.

Comment: Unfortunately, `#pragma once` has become common. The problem is that there are build systems (networks with multiple mount points for the same file system, for example) where it won't work. Which is why the age-old but reliable include guards are still used.

Comment: I understand what pragma is, I'm just trying to understand why compiler spits warnings when pragma is in non header file, but you are totaly right... I think big amount of people here didn't even read what I was asking. and when there was no code because I don't have any problems, since I know how to use pragma and I somehow what is does, they just closed it.

Comment: Don't know if a compiler would emit a warning, but I don't see why. Having `pragma once` in a module shouldn't have an effect, because you compile it only once anyway. And even if you compile it multiple times, you would get the same object file overwriting the previous one.

Comment: @Devolus it will tell you somethink like "pragma once in main file", I don't undestand either, that's why I asked, but looks like "pragma once" is banned word on stack overflow...

Comment: @PavelB. even if it worked in a `cpp` file, it wouldn't make sense anyway. I don't know if it is covered by standard. AFAIK `pragma` is handled compiler specifc and as such it can be implemented as the vendors see fit.